# Troubleshooting Firebase Push Notifications not being received by iOS app

Tags: ios, swiftui, firebase-cloud-messaging

I setup my SwiftUI app to receive notifications from my Firebase account using the example from the Firebase iOS documentation, but when I send a test message, I don't receive anything. I don't see any errors when sending the message through the Firebase console or the OAuth 2.0 Playground so I'm not sure what is wrong. Here's the code I created for my AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseMessaging

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
    
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_ID"
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        // Register for push notifications
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: { _, _ in }
        )
        
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }

    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) async -> UIBackgroundFetchResult {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        return UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData
    }
}


extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification) async -> UNNotificationPresentationOptions {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        
        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
        // [START_EXCLUDE]
        // Print message ID.
        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // [END_EXCLUDE]
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
        
        // Change this to your preferred presentation option
        return UNNotificationPresentationOptions([.banner, .sound])
    }
    
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse) async {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
          print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
        
        // Print full message.
        print(userInfo)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(String(describing: fcmToken))")
        
        let dataDict: [String: String] = ["token": fcmToken ?? ""]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(
            name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"),
            object: nil,
            userInfo: dataDict
        )
        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
        // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
    }
}
```

Here's the code for the main program that initializes the delegate:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {
    @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            MainView()
        }
    }
}
```

When I launch the app, I am able to receive an FCM device token from Firebase, which I used on the console, but no joy. Am I missing something obvious here? What are some steps I can take to find the root issue?